# How do I import specific excel cell values to existing datagridview cells in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, forms, datagridview

I'm having troubles on how to update an existing datagridview loaded with data from mysql with specific excel cell values (not excel sheets) imported from excel.
The available solutions seam to import the entire Sheet and replace the existing datagridview.
And others just make the column blank.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlx;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;

            string name = "sheet1";
            string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
            OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand OleCon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$]", Con);
            Con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleCon);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(data);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Ab"].Value = sda;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Everything BEFORE the `for` loop appears to work as expected… it reads a selected Excel workbook and fills a `DataTable` named `data` with the Excel data. Then the code uses this table as a `DataSource` to the grid. This all appears to work as expected. It is very unclear what you are trying do with the line of code in the `for` loop… `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Ab"].Value = sda;` ? It appears you are trying to set a cells value to the value of an `OleDbDataAdapter` named `sda`??? This will not work. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm populating a datagridview with data from mysql. I want to import some records from an Excel sheet (not all) obtained from another app which updates every time, and then update my datagridview. They can't be updated manually because they are too many. However, this code before the loop imports the whole sheet and replaces the existing datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try query the column directly in the OLEDB command:

```
OleDbCommand OleCon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + " Index$AB]", Con);
```

Comment: But this generates an exception. The Microsoft access database engine could not find the object 'sheet1$ab'.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not understanding what you are trying to do. From what I can decipher, there is a `DataGridView` that that has a `DataSource`. The `DataSource` is a `DataTable` that is created from a query to a database. Also, there is an Excel workbook that has some data you want to use to “overwrite” or add to the `DataGridView`… this is unclear.

From your comments I am guessing that you want to open the Excel file and only read a certain portion of the workbook. As noted, the posted code is reading the whole worksheet named “Sheet1.” If this is correct then this will focus on reading only a certain portion of the workbook.

In your description you state that you want to get … *”specific excel cell values (not excel sheets) imported from excel”* ? … This sounds odd since every cell in a workbook is on a “worksheet.” Therefore, if you want to get specific cells from a workbook… then you MUST also specify a worksheet.

From my tests, this is doable using OLEDB, however there are some caveats that you may want to keep in mind. Also, unless you are forced to use OLEDB, you may want to consider a third-party Excel library reader. There are many out there that are free and from my understanding they are just as good if not better in many ways. However, I am aware that this may not be an option.

IF you wanted to get a “specific” COLUMN of data from an Excel worksheet, the select statement may look something like…

```
OleDbCommand OleCon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Ab FROM [" + name + "$]", Con);
```

For the above select statement to work, as your code does… is to have the header row set to: `HDR=YES` in the provider initialization. Also, the column name (`Ab`) cannot have spaces. If the header has spaces you have to enclose it with a single quote “`”. This is the single quote from the tilde “~” key. The double quote””” key will not work. If you use the double quote key, it will be interpreted as a literal and will simply fill the column with that value.
From this you can select any column or columns that you want.

```
OleDbCommand OleCon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Ab, 'Expense Description' FROM [" + name + "$]", Con);
```

Now the bad news, Excel has a nasty habit of reporting cells as “containing” a value when they don’t. Example, using the above select statements on an existing Excel worksheet that only has 1000 rows of data returned 49,999 rows. I created a new workbook and added some data and the above command only returned the cells that contained data. Point being… that if you use this strategy, it may be prudent to check what is returned. I am confident this will be obvious when the `Fill` takes 15 seconds or more.

Another approach is to select the cells using Excel’s range type definition. Something like…

```
OleDbCommand OleCon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$B1:C1000]", Con);
```

Here, you can define a range of cells. The downside here is that the columns must be contiguous or at least I was unable to create non-contiguous ranges. I understand that you can use a “defined” named range from the workbook, however I was unable to achieve this.

After you have these cells, I am not sure how you would match each row to the rows in the grid, however I assume this would be the next step.

I hope this helps.